# Induced charge due to charge distribution between two plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I am trying to work through this problem:  given two parallel square conducting plates (side w), one grounded(at x=0) and the other held at +V (at x=L where L < < w), and there is a charge distribution $\rho(\vec x)$ (arbitrary, not given) between them.  What is the charge accumulated on each plate, i terms of the moments of the distribution?

My issue comes in trying to find the potential.  In general:
$$\phi=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\vec x')}{|x-x'|}d^3x'$$
Which can be expanded in terms of the charge distribution moments $q_{lm}$
$$\phi=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\sum_{l,m}\frac{q_{l,m}Y_{lm}}{(2l+1)r^{l+1}}$$

This expression blows up at the origin (i.e the grounded plate), so I am not sure how to account for that.  Should I have some kind of sine envelope with this potential, so that it vanishes at x=0?  Possibly use a greens function with dirichlet boundary conditions?

Comment: So it is not a capacitor, it is just two conducting plates.  There is no capacitance given (eventually want to solve for it).  But we need to find the charge on the plates in terms of moments of the charge density

Comment: First problem is with your geometry, don't use spherical expansions for non-spherical symmetries, since there is no spherical symmetry here. Also, you must have some sort of definition of the charge density, the general case can be quite challenging; even ignoring border effects.

Are the plates infinite? More details are certainly needed to solve this problem.

Comment: So all we have is the charge density rho, the plates are separated by a distance d, and the plates are a square with side w (x>>d), and one is help at ground, the other at V

Comment: So, to be more clear, is $\rho$ constant? Is the problem from Jackson?

Comment: $rho$ is arbitrary, could be constant, could not be.  This is not from jackson

Answer (score 1):

Instead of solving *Laplace's equation*, you need to consider *Poisson's equation*. The reason for this is that you have free charges available in the enclosed region between two plates. However, you should solve this equation in *Cartesian* coordinates along with imposing the *boundary conditions.* For this particular problem, this methodology would be more appropriate than the multipole moment expansion. The *singularity* you claim for vanishingly small distances will be removed if *boundary conditions* is applied correctly.

Another way of approaching it would be *Green's* Function methodology where you need to realize that your boundary conditions are of *Dirichlet* type.

Take a look at the following documents where particular charge distributions are considered too:

[Poisson's Equation in Cartesian Coordinates](http://topex.ucsd.edu/geodynamics/15gravity2_2.pdf)

[Example: Charge filled Parallel Plates](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/220/handouts/Example%20Charge%20Filled%20Parallel%20Plates.pdf)

[Multipole Moments in Electrostatics](http://info.phys.unm.edu/~ideutsch/Classes/Phys511S99/Handouts/Mulipole_expansion_notes.pdf)

Comment: So I believe (from wikipedia) that the greens function for poissons equation is $$G=[(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2]^{-1/2}$$, which means $\phi = \int dV' G(x,y,z,x',y',z')\rho(x',y',z')$  I do not see how this results in something I can find the moments of

Comment: Or is that G only free space?  Seeing as it does not meet any of the BC (which because of dirichlet should be 0 correct?)

Comment: Why are you insisting on a need to find moments? Do you really need them? Also, is your charge distribution really unknown?

Comment: The exact wording is: "A blob of charge of density ρ(x) lies between two square conducting plates of side w that are separated by distance d<<w.
One plate is grounded and the other held at potential V. 
Write expressions for the charge on each plate in terms of
moments of the charge density.

Comment: Added to my response is also another paper (No. 3) which particularly discusses multipole expansion methodology in Cartesian Coordinates.

Comment: That approach has the same $r^{-l}$ dependance that causes issues satisfying the BC

Comment: Are you making sure that you are applying your initial conditions of V(x=0)=0 and V(x=L)=V? They will result in non-trivial equations where you can deduce values for some of your coefficients.

Comment: This is my last comment and I hope it will help you. It might be the case that your first moment (that is total enclosed charge) is actually such that it removed the dependency on 1/r. For example this would be the case if you have q linear in r.

Comment: Just thinking about things, how about applying a special case of  the "method of images" to the problem? This problem should exhibit enough symmetry so that it can be applied, I'm just hoping that $\rho(\vec{x})=\rho(\left|\vec{x}\right|)$. You can find this method in many books.